# How to get total using php while in a session..?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm having a trouble when I'm going to get sum while using a session,

this is my database table named owes..

```
   email           date        name   amount  

 abc@gamil.com    11/05/2014   Ann    1000.00 
 abc@gmail.com    20/06/2014   Ann    500.00 
 bcd@gmail.com    13/04/2014   Jane   700.00 
 bcd@gmail.com    11/05/2014   Anne   300.00 
 abc@gamil.com    09/05/2014   Amal   1500.00
```

when I'm logging as abc@gamil.com (also session=abc@gamil.com ) I want to get the SUM of name's as follows..

Ann  1500.00 
Amal 1500.00

if session=bcd@gmail.com ,then..

Ann  300.00 
jane 700.00

And I've used following php code,

```
<?php

session_start();
$user= $_SESSION['email'];
echo $user;

?>

    </br></br>
    <a href="../transaction/owes.php">New loan</a>
    </br>
    <a href="../transaction/d1.php">Delete</a>
    </br></br>



<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","core");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$sql= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM owes WHERE email='$user'") ;
$sql1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT name FROM owes WHERE email='$user'") ;
$sql2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name,SUM(amount) AS total FROM owes GROUP BY name ") ;



  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){


while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){

                                                                                             if($user==$row['email']){              

                echo $row1['name'];
            echo "</br>";


        }

    }

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){


        if($user==$row['email']){


            echo $row2['total'];
            echo "</br>";


        }
    }




}


  ?>
```

When I use this code I'm getting as follows,

Ann  1800.00 
Amal 1500.00 
     700.00 (From jane, name not indicated b'coz session = abc2gmail.com )

But I can get correct figures without using session, but I want it with session,

Comment: You should [escape](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) your strings before passing them to the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `where` clause to this query

```
SELECT name,SUM(amount) AS total FROM owes GROUP BY name
```

something like

```
SELECT name,SUM(amount) AS total FROM owes where email ='EMAIL_PARAMS' GROUP BY name
```